# Centos8 podman exiting all containers (139)

Tags: centos, containers, podman

Any image I would try to run the behavior is always the same "Exited (139)"

OS: Centos 8 with podman running inside an Azure VM. The Centos image is the one provided by Azure when creating a VM.

VM: Azure B2S Gen 2 | 2vCPU(s) | 4 GiB RAM | 8 GiB SSD

I paste below the exact extract from the terminal:

**pull**

```
$ podman pull fedora
Trying to pull registry.access.redhat.com/fedora...
  name unknown: Repo not found
Trying to pull registry.redhat.io/fedora...
  unable to retrieve auth token: invalid username/password: unauthorized: Please login to the Red Hat Registry using your Customer Portal credentials. Further instructions can be found here: https://access.redhat.com/RegistryAuthentication
Trying to pull docker.io/library/fedora...
Getting image source signatures
Copying blob ae7b613df528 done
Copying config b3048463dc done
Writing manifest to image destination
Storing signatures
b3048463dcefbe4920ef2ae1af43171c9695e2077f315b2bc12ed0f6f67c86c7
```

**run**

```
$ podman run --rm fedora /bin/echo "Hello Geeks! Welcome to Podman"
```

**ps**

```
$ podman ps -a
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE                            COMMAND  CREATED        STATUS                      PORTS   NAMES
feb43e01e777  docker.io/library/ubuntu:latest  bash     3 minutes ago  Exited (139) 3 minutes ago          magical_carson
```

**inspect**

```
$ podman inspect feb43e01e777
[
    {
        "Id": "feb43e01e7771ca0a5a1b4cdf5a7b2587341493f1ecd7b2723d1ad5a45076aac",
        "Created": "2020-12-10T11:35:16.863809294Z",
        "Path": "bash",
        "Args": [
            "bash"
        ],
        "State": {
            "OciVersion": "1.0.2-dev",
            "Status": "exited",
            "Running": false,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 0,
            "ExitCode": 139,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2020-12-10T11:35:17.280743295Z",
            "FinishedAt": "2020-12-10T11:35:17.280874897Z",
            "Healthcheck": {
                "Status": "",
                "FailingStreak": 0,
                "Log": null
            }
        },
        "Image": "f643c72bc25212974c16f3348b3a898b1ec1eb13ec1539e10a103e6e217eb2f1",
        "ImageName": "docker.io/library/ubuntu:latest",
        "Rootfs": "",
        "Pod": "",
        "ResolvConfPath": "/run/user/1000/containers/overlay-containers/feb43e01e7771ca0a5a1b4cdf5a7b2587341493f1ecd7b2723d1ad5a45076aac/userdata/resolv.conf",
        "HostnamePath": "/run/user/1000/containers/overlay-containers/feb43e01e7771ca0a5a1b4cdf5a7b2587341493f1ecd7b2723d1ad5a45076aac/userdata/hostname",
        "HostsPath": "/run/user/1000/containers/overlay-containers/feb43e01e7771ca0a5a1b4cdf5a7b2587341493f1ecd7b2723d1ad5a45076aac/userdata/hosts",
        "StaticDir": "/home/brais/.local/share/containers/storage/overlay-containers/feb43e01e7771ca0a5a1b4cdf5a7b2587341493f1ecd7b2723d1ad5a45076aac/userdata",
        "OCIConfigPath": "/home/brais/.local/share/containers/storage/overlay-containers/feb43e01e7771ca0a5a1b4cdf5a7b2587341493f1ecd7b2723d1ad5a45076aac/userdata/config.json",
        "OCIRuntime": "runc",
        "LogPath": "/home/brais/.local/share/containers/storage/overlay-containers/feb43e01e7771ca0a5a1b4cdf5a7b2587341493f1ecd7b2723d1ad5a45076aac/userdata/ctr.log",
        "LogTag": "",
        "ConmonPidFile": "/run/user/1000/containers/overlay-containers/feb43e01e7771ca0a5a1b4cdf5a7b2587341493f1ecd7b2723d1ad5a45076aac/userdata/conmon.pid",
        "Name": "magical_carson",
        "RestartCount": 0,
        "Driver": "overlay",
        "MountLabel": "system_u:object_r:container_file_t:s0:c375,c701",
        "ProcessLabel": "system_u:system_r:container_t:s0:c375,c701",
        "AppArmorProfile": "",
        "EffectiveCaps": [
            "CAP_AUDIT_WRITE",
            "CAP_CHOWN",
            "CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE",
            "CAP_FOWNER",
            "CAP_FSETID",
            "CAP_KILL",
            "CAP_MKNOD",
            "CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE",
            "CAP_NET_RAW",
            "CAP_SETFCAP",
            "CAP_SETGID",
            "CAP_SETPCAP",
            "CAP_SETUID",
            "CAP_SYS_CHROOT"
        ],
        "BoundingCaps": [
            "CAP_AUDIT_WRITE",
            "CAP_CHOWN",
            "CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE",
            "CAP_FOWNER",
            "CAP_FSETID",
            "CAP_KILL",
            "CAP_MKNOD",
            "CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE",
            "CAP_NET_RAW",
            "CAP_SETFCAP",
            "CAP_SETGID",
            "CAP_SETPCAP",
            "CAP_SETUID",
            "CAP_SYS_CHROOT"
        ],
        "ExecIDs": [],
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Name": "overlay",
            "Data": {
                "LowerDir": "/home/brais/.local/share/containers/storage/overlay/6581dd55e4fe0935a32a688d74513db86632efb162fd41431e7d69318802dfae/diff:/home/brais/.local/share/containers/storage/overlay/1bd27dc7c1c2e7a36c599becda69d0cd905f4f1a122f2b7a95c81a78abc452ec/diff:/home/brais/.local/share/containers/storage/overlay/bacd3af13903e13a43fe87b6944acd1ff21024132aad6e74b4452d984fb1a99a/diff",
                "UpperDir": "/home/brais/.local/share/containers/storage/overlay/ccc5801aaacb05d0ed1e64cee2e38f7b4dd8a29890e6fdf780887d296a1c9696/diff",
                "WorkDir": "/home/brais/.local/share/containers/storage/overlay/ccc5801aaacb05d0ed1e64cee2e38f7b4dd8a29890e6fdf780887d296a1c9696/work"
            }
        },
        "Mounts": [],
        "Dependencies": [],
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "EndpointID": "",
            "Gateway": "",
            "IPAddress": "",
            "IPPrefixLen": 0,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "MacAddress": "",
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {},
            "SandboxKey": ""
        },
        "ExitCommand": [
            "/usr/bin/podman",
            "--root",
            "/home/brais/.local/share/containers/storage",
            "--runroot",
            "/run/user/1000/containers",
            "--log-level",
            "error",
            "--cgroup-manager",
            "cgroupfs",
            "--tmpdir",
            "/run/user/1000/libpod/tmp",
            "--runtime",
            "runc",
            "--storage-driver",
            "overlay",
            "--storage-opt",
            "overlay.mount_program=/usr/bin/fuse-overlayfs",
            "--events-backend",
            "file",
            "container",
            "cleanup",
            "feb43e01e7771ca0a5a1b4cdf5a7b2587341493f1ecd7b2723d1ad5a45076aac"
        ],
        "Namespace": "",
        "IsInfra": false,
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "feb43e01e777",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "Tty": true,
            "OpenStdin": true,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "TERM=xterm",
                "container=podman",
                "HOSTNAME=feb43e01e777",
                "HOME=/root"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "bash"
            ],
            "Image": "docker.io/library/ubuntu:latest",
            "Volumes": null,
            "WorkingDir": "/",
            "Entrypoint": "",
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": null,
            "Annotations": {
                "io.container.manager": "libpod",
                "io.kubernetes.cri-o.Created": "2020-12-10T11:35:16.863809294Z",
                "io.kubernetes.cri-o.TTY": "true",
                "io.podman.annotations.autoremove": "FALSE",
                "io.podman.annotations.init": "FALSE",
                "io.podman.annotations.privileged": "FALSE",
                "io.podman.annotations.publish-all": "FALSE",
                "org.opencontainers.image.stopSignal": "15"
            },
            "StopSignal": 15,
            "CreateCommand": [
                "podman",
                "run",
                "-it",
                "ubuntu",
                "bash"
            ]
        },
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": [],
            "CgroupMode": "host",
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "k8s-file",
                "Config": null
            },
            "NetworkMode": "slirp4netns",
            "PortBindings": {},
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
            "AutoRemove": false,
            "VolumeDriver": "",
            "VolumesFrom": null,
            "CapAdd": [],
            "CapDrop": [],
            "Dns": [],
            "DnsOptions": [],
            "DnsSearch": [],
            "ExtraHosts": [],
            "GroupAdd": [],
            "IpcMode": "private",
            "Cgroup": "",
            "Cgroups": "default",
            "Links": null,
            "OomScoreAdj": 0,
            "PidMode": "private",
            "Privileged": false,
            "PublishAllPorts": false,
            "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
            "SecurityOpt": [],
            "Tmpfs": {},
            "UTSMode": "private",
            "UsernsMode": "",
            "ShmSize": 65536000,
            "Runtime": "oci",
            "ConsoleSize": [
                0,
                0
            ],
            "Isolation": "",
            "CpuShares": 0,
            "Memory": 0,
            "NanoCpus": 0,
            "CgroupParent": "",
            "BlkioWeight": 0,
            "BlkioWeightDevice": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
            "CpuPeriod": 0,
            "CpuQuota": 0,
            "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
            "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
            "CpusetCpus": "",
            "CpusetMems": "",
            "Devices": [],
            "DiskQuota": 0,
            "KernelMemory": 0,
            "MemoryReservation": 0,
            "MemorySwap": 0,
            "MemorySwappiness": 0,
            "OomKillDisable": false,
            "PidsLimit": 0,
            "Ulimits": [],
            "CpuCount": 0,
            "CpuPercent": 0,
            "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
            "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0
        }
    }
]
```

**podman info**

```
$ podman info
host:
  arch: amd64
  buildahVersion: 1.15.1
  cgroupVersion: v1
  conmon:
    package: conmon-2.0.20-2.module_el8.3.0+475+c50ce30b.x86_64
    path: /usr/bin/conmon
    version: 'conmon version 2.0.20, commit: 1019ecdeda3936be22162bb1cca308192145de53'
  cpus: 2
  distribution:
    distribution: '"centos"'
    version: "8"
  eventLogger: file
  hostname: vm-test1
  idMappings:
    gidmap:
    - container_id: 0
      host_id: 1000
      size: 1
    - container_id: 1
      host_id: 100000
      size: 65536
    uidmap:
    - container_id: 0
      host_id: 1000
      size: 1
    - container_id: 1
      host_id: 100000
      size: 65536
  kernel: 4.18.0-193.28.1.el8_2.x86_64
  linkmode: dynamic
  memFree: 247398400
  memTotal: 4129382400
  ociRuntime:
    name: runc
    package: runc-1.0.0-68.rc92.module_el8.3.0+475+c50ce30b.x86_64
    path: /usr/bin/runc
    version: 'runc version spec: 1.0.2-dev'
  os: linux
  remoteSocket:
    path: /run/user/1000/podman/podman.sock
  rootless: true
  slirp4netns:
    executable: /usr/bin/slirp4netns
    package: slirp4netns-1.1.4-2.module_el8.3.0+475+c50ce30b.x86_64
    version: |-
      slirp4netns version 1.1.4
      commit: b66ffa8e262507e37fca689822d23430f3357fe8
      libslirp: 4.3.1
      SLIRP_CONFIG_VERSION_MAX: 3
  swapFree: 0
  swapTotal: 0
  uptime: 17h 48m 18.07s (Approximately 0.71 days)
registries:
  search:
  - registry.access.redhat.com
  - registry.redhat.io
  - docker.io
store:
  configFile: /home/brais/.config/containers/storage.conf
  containerStore:
    number: 1
    paused: 0
    running: 0
    stopped: 1
  graphDriverName: overlay
  graphOptions:
    overlay.mount_program:
      Executable: /usr/bin/fuse-overlayfs
      Package: fuse-overlayfs-1.1.2-3.module_el8.3.0+507+aa0970ae.x86_64
      Version: |-
        fuse-overlayfs: version 1.1.0
        FUSE library version 3.2.1
        using FUSE kernel interface version 7.26
  graphRoot: /home/brais/.local/share/containers/storage
  graphStatus:
    Backing Filesystem: xfs
    Native Overlay Diff: "false"
    Supports d_type: "true"
    Using metacopy: "false"
  imageStore:
    number: 8
  runRoot: /run/user/1000/containers
  volumePath: /home/brais/.local/share/containers/storage/volumes
version:
  APIVersion: 1
  Built: 1600970293
  BuiltTime: Thu Sep 24 17:58:13 2020
  GitCommit: ""
  GoVersion: go1.14.7
  OsArch: linux/amd64
  Version: 2.0.5
```

Comment: Maybe this will work: Instead of `/bin/echo "Hello Geeks! Welcome to Podman"`, try `sleep 60` for a command that takes a bit longer to execute. Or maybe `bash -c "echo hello && sleep 60"`

Comment: It does not matter what command you put, with any image the execution always ends with 139 error